# How to query json doc from mysql DB when json doc has multiple same key with different values as part of array

Tags: mysql, json

```
{
    x: [
        {
            a: daodao,
            b: daodao1
        },
        {
            a: daodao,
            b: daodao2
        }  
    ],
    y: some-string,
    z: some-string
}
```

- I need to query json doc based on "b": "daodao1".

  Do we have support in mysql 5.7 where we can query such json doc mentioned below

Comment: What JSON document structure do you expect as a result of the query?. Can you leave an example?.